# Javascript Recursive function seems to exit after first pass

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am trying to render a tree like hierarchy while recursing through set a nodes (**index**). I already know the roots(**top**). There are multiple root elements. I am trying to collect the entire html in the variable **tree** (this entire html will be appended to a div later)

```
tree = "";
top = ["1", "11", "14", "17", "72", "73", "74", "78", "79", "98", "99"];
index = {
    1: {
        'name': "Node 1",
        'children': "2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"
    },
    2: {
        'name': "Node 2",
        'children': ""
    },

//.... goes all the way upto 99
}
```

The recursive function makeFT(index,roots) only seems to break after traversing the children of first element in the "top" array.

The code for this is at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ugoju4/2/edit) and below. What could be the problem? Is there a better way to do this? Any help is appreciated.

```
makeFT(index, top);


function makeFT(index, roots) {
    console.log(roots);
    tree == "" ? tree += '<ul>' : tree += '<ul><hr/>'
    for (i = 0; i < roots.length; ++i) {
        n = parseInt(roots[i]);
        //console.log(n);
        //console.log(index[n]);

        tree += '<li>' + roots[i] + '</span>' + index[n].name;

        if (index[n].children === "") {
            tree += '<input class="leaf tree-first-input" type="text" size="2">'
        }
        else {
            tree += '<input class="non-leaf tree-first-input" type="text" size="2">'
            makeFT(index, index[n].children.split(","));
        }
        tree += "</li>"
    }
    tree += '</ul><br/>'

}
```

UPDATE : Turns out this is a scoping problem and not a recursion problem. The recursion was alright. Since I did not define scope of the variable 'i' while looping through roots array, each subsequent recursed function inherited the value of unscoped 'i' thereby creating the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a var i=0 inside the function. You have scoping issues with i.

http://jsbin.com/ugoju4/12/edit

Comment: Also adding `var n` and `var tree` are recommended to avoid future bugs

Comment: @Tomas, thanks. Yes, I will add the relevant scope. Missed the  'var i' part as a result of which Each subsequent recursed function inherited the value of i. Brilliant find by rcravens.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from your recursive function.

```
  }
        else {
            tree += '<input class="non-leaf tree-first-input" type="text" size="2">'
            tree += makeFT(index, index[n].children.split(","));
        }
        tree += "</li>"
    }
    tree += '</ul><br/>'
    return tree;
 }
```

This should give you the value. Use it to write it to an element by Id. Updated the jsfiddle

Comment: I think tree is a global defined variable, so this function must not return any value.

Comment: This problem is occurring irrespective of whether I return a value or not. Give it a try urself.

Comment: @EvilMM You should, check the updated jsfiddle code, http://jsbin.com/ugoju4/11/edit

Answer (score 0):

`top` is a global variable referring to the "top" window of the current frame set. Use a different variable name.

Answer (score -1):

1. Why you type "++i" in you for-statement? Use "i++"
2. You are typing

   index[n].children === ""

try it with

```
index[n].children == ""
```

I think he never runs in the else-part.

Comment: `i++` or `++i` in the for statement does not differ at all.

Comment: In addition, since children is a string, `===` is the correct operator (-1)